# Pyton Envio de infomacion del sistema unix por correo

Tags: python-3.x, email, unix, smtp

Estoy tratando de generar un script en python3 que al ejecutar me envie a mi correo personal una serie de información de mi sistema en la nube con centos7, en concreto la salida de un comando sobre varios servicios: Apache, Mysql, pptp... pero me encuentro con un problema.El objetivo es tener mas o menos controlado mi servidor web y los servicios que dependen del. Este es código y problema:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import subprocess
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

ApacheStatus = subprocess.call(['systemctl','status','httpd'])
MysqlStatus = subprocess.call(['systemctl','status','mysqld'])
PptpdStatus = subprocess.call(['systemctl', 'status', 'pptpd'])

# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
```

hasta aquí bien,ahora guardo la información genera por el comando en varias variables: `ApacheStatus`, `MysqlStatus`, `PptpdStatus` y se las paso al contenido del mensaje que quiero enviar. Asi:

```
message = ApacheStatus

password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
msg['From'] = "silicom33@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "adasdasd21312@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Prueba-Python"

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()

server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print
"Email enviado correctamente %s:" % (msg['To'])
```

Al ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente error  no llega a enviar nada

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StatusServerCorreo.py", line 24, in <module>
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/email/mime/text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

De lo contrario si formateo la variable *message* como string, asi:

```
message = ApacheStatus
```

me envia un correo con el siguiente cuerpo:

```
0
```

Ni más ni menos. En que me equivoco? Estoy formateando mal la salida del comando del sistema (centos7)?

Gracias y estamos en contacto

Comment: Vistazo rápido: Posiblemente el call retorna el id del estado del proceso y habría que revisar cómo entregar el mensaje que normalmente ves en consola.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a otras [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344182/236345), podrías obtener algo más que el ID del estado del proceso así:

```
import subprocess
service = "httpd"

p =  subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "is-active",  service], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
output = output.decode('utf-8')

print(output)
```